# can't read from .txt file using istringstream

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

I'm trying to write a fairly basic program, that reads a .txt file using istringstream, but for some reason this code:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    std::string filename = "test.txt";
    std::stringstream file(filename);
    while (std::getline(file, filename))
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << filename;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

only prints:
    test.txt

The file i'm trying to read is a .txt file named test.txt created by windows editor containg:
test1
test2
test3
I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Are you sure you want a ***string*** stream and not a file stream like `std::ifstream`? The program does exactly what you tell it to do, which is create a string stream with the string `"test.txt"` which you then read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your goal was to read each of the entries in the file, you are using the wrong class. For reading from files, you need [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), and would use it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    std::string filename = "test.txt";
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            std::cout << "\n" << line;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Handling for file not able to be opened
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<newline>
test1
test2
test3
```

[Live Example](https://repl.it/repls/SuperbBleakAmericanredsquirrel)

[`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) is used for parsing strings, not files.